# Can't call a class on setOnItemClickListener on first click in android

Tags: java, android, class

i have a `gridview`. if an item from that grid is clicked, it will call a class named `get_details`. my problem is that on first click of any item from the grid, it skips `new get_details().execute();` but after my next click it is working already.. can you please help me..

here's my code

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {


            final globalVars globalVars = (globalVars) getApplicationContext();


            String sel_id = ca_list.get(arg2).stud_id;
            globalVars.setClickedGrid(sel_id);
            Log.i("SELECT", sel_id);

            new get_details().execute();

            String p_id = globalVars.getPopupID().toString();
            String p_name = globalVars.getPopupName().toString();
            String p_absent = globalVars.getPopupAbsent().toString();
            String p_late = globalVars.getPopupLate().toString();
            Log.i("SHOW CALL" , p_name);

            int y = arg1.getTop();
            int x = arg1.getLeft();

                 showPopup(ViewAttendanceSP.this, x, y, p_id, p_name, p_absent, p_late);

        }
       });
```

get_details class

```
private class  get_details extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> 
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
    {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";


        String bidSt = dispid.getText().toString();
        globalVars globalVars = (globalVars)getApplicationContext();
        String idSt = globalVars.getClickedGrid().toString();

        try 
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.59.1/sp/viewsumsp.php");

            List<NameValuePair> parameter = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("student_id", idSt));
            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("beadle_id", bidSt));


            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameter));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        try 
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> to_take = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        try 
        {
            JSONObject jArray = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONArray stud_info = jArray.getJSONArray("stud_info");
            ca_list1 = new ArrayList<ViewAttendanceSummaryObject>();

            for (int i = 0; i < stud_info.length(); i++) 
            {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject e = stud_info.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("stud_id", e.getString("student_id"));
                map.put("f_name", e.getString("first_name"));
                map.put("l_name", e.getString("last_name"));
                map.put("absence", e.getString("absence"));
                map.put("lateness", e.getString("lateness"));

                to_take.add(map);
                Log.i("INNER" , e.getString("first_name"));

                final globalVars globalVars = (globalVars) getApplicationContext();

                String id = e.getString("student_id");
                String name = e.getString("last_name") + ", " + e.getString("first_name");
                String abs = e.getString("absence");
                String lat = e.getString("lateness");

                globalVars.setPopupID(id);
                globalVars.setPopupName(name);
                globalVars.setPopupAbsent(abs);
                globalVars.setPopupLate(lat);

                ca_list1.add(new ViewAttendanceSummaryObject(e.getString("student_id"), e.getString("first_name"), e.getString("last_name"), e.getString("absence"), e.getString("lateness")));
            }



        } catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

p.s. i just found out that, it does not skip new get_details().execute(); rather it stops after new get_details().execute(); is executed.. how do i fix this?

Comment: if `String bidSt = dispid.getText().toString();` `dispid` is Ui element then how it's working first time or second time because you are trying to access Ui element in doInBackground

Answer (score 0):

use `onPreExecute` for accessing UI elements inside `AsyncTask` as :

```
private class  get_details extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> 
{
     String bidSt="";
       @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //access all Ui elements here
        bidSt = dispid.getText().toString();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
    {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
         //your code here
```

because it's not possible to access Ui elements from doInBackground in AsyncTask.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i just found out that, it does not skip new get_details().execute(); rather it stops after new get_details().execute(); is executed.. how do i fix this?

Comment: post your catlog when it's crashing . i'm stuck how it's working if dispid is Ui element.

Comment: it does not crash. so i think there is nothing wrong with my dispid.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are seeing the desired behavior of an `AsyncTask`. It will operate in the background and then publish its results to the main UI thread, so it may not appear as if it is operating immediately.

According the [`AsyncTask` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) it should be a fairly short operation, few seconds max. How long is your operation taking? If your background task is supposed to process every click on your `GridView`, then it should be short enough that it can usually finish before the user is able to click again. Otherwise you could potentially create a queue of background tasks that may take too long to publish results to the user.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i just found out that, it does not skip new get_details().execute(); rather it stops after new get_details().execute(); is executed.. how do i fix this?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "stop"? Does an exception get thrown?

Comment: sorry, what i meant by stop is that there are no errors and it skips this part String p_id = globalVars.getPopupID().toString();
          String p_name = globalVars.getPopupName().toString();
          String p_absent = globalVars.getPopupAbsent().toString();
          String p_late = globalVars.getPopupLate().toString();
          Log.i("SHOW CALL" , p_name);of the setonclicklistener and it will continue unless i click another item..

Comment: You would see the behavior you are describing if you are experiencing an deadlock between the background thread and the main UI thread. @imran_khan alluded to this. You are referencing a number of the same variables in both threads. Check out the best practices of the Memory Observability section of [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: i have solved my problem already.. and it is a logic error. thanks by the way.

Comment: If you found your own solution, you should answer your own question so you can explain the root of your problem and help others who see this post.